# Calculator Based on ATMega8 using AVRstudi

Tags: c++, c, calculator, avr

About the Calculator:

Basically this calculator is made to calculate the resistance of copper and aluminum wires at the ambient temperature using the formula
R2= R1*(1+alpha(T-25))

Here R2 will be the output, R1 will be the value entered by the user using a 4x4 matrix keypad (which will include decimal values like 12.5 etc), T is the temperature in degree Celsius recorded by the temperature sensor LM35.
alpha for copper = 0.0039
alpha for aluminum = 0.0042

How it should work:

Basically the temperature will be recorded by the calculator which will give the input T. The value of resistance at 25deg C will be fed by the user using keypad.
Now the keys 0-9 and "." are used to enter the value.
After this when the user presses say "+"  on keypad, it should implement the formula for copper and show the result on LCD, similarly when the user presses "-" it should implement the formula for aluminum. Let us leave the "*" "/" and "=" buttons as spare for the time being.

Progress till now:

Using the codes which I have sent you in this attachment, I am able to get the temperature on screen correctly, I am able to see the value of R1 (i.e value of resistance at 25deg C) Now I cannot figure out how to use these values to get the output.

Please help me with this. :)

Thanks & Regards,
Mohit Goyal

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "lcd.h"
#include "lcd.c"
#include <math.h>
#define KB_PORT_OUT PORTB
#define KB_PORT_IN PINB
void port_init(void)
{

DDRB  = 0x0f;       //Key-board port, higer nibble - input, lower nibble -     output
 PORTB = 0xff;  
}
 void init_devices(void)
{
port_init();

 MCUCR = 0x00;
 TIMSK = 0x00; //timer interrupt sources
 } 

void InitADC()
{
ADMUX=(1<<REFS0);
ADCSRA=(1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);

}
uint16_t ReadADC (uint8_t ch)
{
ch=ch&0b00000111;
ADMUX|=ch;
ADCSRA|=(1<<ADSC);
while (! (ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF)));
ADCSRA|=(1<<ADIF);
return (ADC);
}
void Wait ()
{
uint8_t i;
for (i=0;i<1;i++)
_delay_loop_2(0);
}
void main()   
{

char Temp[3];
uint16_t adc_result,mV;
int t;
lcd_init (LCD_DISP_ON);
lcd_clrscr();
InitADC();
lcd_gotoxy(0,0);
lcd_puts("R1=");
lcd_gotoxy(9,0);
lcd_puts(",T=");
lcd_gotoxy(15,0);
lcd_puts("C");
lcd_gotoxy(0,1);
lcd_puts("R2=");
while(1)
{
adc_result=ReadADC(0);
mV=(int)(1000.0*5.0*(((float)adc_result)/1023.0));
t=(int)(mV/10);
sprintf(Temp,"%d",t);
lcd_gotoxy(12,0);
lcd_puts(Temp);
Wait();
unsigned char Res, upperNibble, myCharPointer, keyCode, keyPressed, j;
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0, display=0;
 init_devices();


 lcd_gotoxy(3,0);
 while(1)
 {
    upperNibble = 0xff;

    for(j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
     _delay_ms(1);
     KB_PORT_OUT = ~(0x01 << j);
     _delay_ms(1);                        //delay for port o/p settling
     upperNibble = KB_PORT_IN | 0x0f;

     if (upperNibble != 0xff)
     {
       _delay_ms(20);                //key debouncing delay
       upperNibble = KB_PORT_IN | 0x0f;
       if(upperNibble == 0xff) goto OUT;

       keyCode = (upperNibble & 0xf0) | (0x0f & ~(0x01 << j));

       while (upperNibble != 0xff)
         upperNibble = KB_PORT_IN | 0x0f;

       _delay_ms(20);                  //key debouncing delay

       switch (keyCode)            //generating key characetr to display on LCD
       {
        case (0xee): keyPressed = "1"; 
        a=1;
        b=b*10+1;
                     break;
        case (0xed): keyPressed = "4";
        a=4;
        b=b*10+4;
                     break;
        case (0xeb): keyPressed = "7"; 
        a=7;
        b=b*10+7;
                     break;
        case (0xe7): keyPressed = "."; 

                     break;
        case (0xde): keyPressed = "2"; 
        a=2;
        b=b*10+2;
                     break;
        case (0xdd): keyPressed = "5"; 
        a=5;
        b=b*10+5;
                     break;
        case (0xdb): keyPressed = "8"; 
        a=8;
        b=b*10+8;
                     break;
        case (0xd7): keyPressed = "0"; 
        a=0;
        b=b*10+0;
                     break;
        case (0xbe): keyPressed = "3"; 
        a=3;
        b=b*10+3;
                     break;
        case (0xbd): keyPressed = "6"; 
        a=6;
        b=b*10+6;
                     break;
        case (0xbb): keyPressed = "9"; 
        a=9;
        b=b*10+9;
                     break;
        case (0xb7): keyPressed = "="; 
                     break;
        case (0x7e): keyPressed = "A"; 
                     break;
        case (0x7d): keyPressed = "B"; 
                     break;
        case (0x7b): keyPressed = "C"; 
                     break;
        case (0x77): keyPressed = "D"; 
                     break;
        default    : keyPressed = "X";
        }//end of switch

        lcd_puts(keyPressed);

 lcd_gotoxy(3,1);
 lcd_puts(keyPressed);










       OUT:;
      }//end of if
    }//end of for
}//end of while(1)  

return 0; 
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to  read input is read characters in character array(in your switch case block append keypressed to character array using `strcat` function). Then check whether it is in right format. And then convert the number in character array to float and use it in calculation as explained in [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494218/how-to-convert-char-into-float/18494338#18494338)

The way to append keypressed to string:

```
char s[25]="";
strcat(s,"1")
```

There is one error I noticed 
Change

```
keypressed="1"
```

to

```
keypressed='1'
```

in  all such cases. "1" is const character array. '1' is character

or change the type of keypressed character array and use strcpy to assign any string to  it.

```
strcpy(keypressed,"1")
```

Comment: Hi my problem is pretty much solved.. I have another problem now, my microcontroller doesn't process floating type values so how can I do operations on floating type values using int?

Comment: This problem has been solved thanx all..

Please move to the new problem :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506198/how-to-store-a-number-in-decimal-format-in-avr

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote you,, M really sorry and thanks a lot for helping me out :)